# Magento 2 code-migration tool not migrate setup script?

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I just tried the official code migration tools try to convert the m1 module to m2 module, in m1 source "sql" folder which is the setup/install script, but after i ran all migration command, i didn't find installData.php in destination. 
Here is the log

```
[2018-07-27 04:01:54][INFO]: Starting module structure converter
[2018-07-27 04:01:54][WARNING]: 0 modules were converted
[2018-07-27 04:01:54][INFO]: Ending module structure converter
[2018-07-27 04:03:14][INFO]: Starting module structure converter
[2018-07-27 04:03:14][INFO][stage: M1][codePool: local]: Processing M1 codepool
[2018-07-27 04:03:14][INFO][stage: M1][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Processing Module
[2018-07-27 04:03:14][INFO][stage: M2][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Converting 10 files found in module
[2018-07-27 04:03:14][INFO][stage: M2][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Ending module structure converter
[2018-07-27 05:02:20][INFO]: Starting etc config xml converter for D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst
[2018-07-27 05:02:20][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\.\module.xml
[2018-07-27 05:02:20][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\.\config.xml
[2018-07-27 05:02:20][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\adminhtml\system.xml
[2018-07-27 05:02:20][INFO]: Ending etc config xml converter
[2018-07-27 05:03:20][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Helper/Data.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Helper/Data.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type resource_model
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type resource_model
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mode.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map alias Custom_Module of type helper
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Class not found for alias "Custom_Module"
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map helper class: 'Custom_Module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mode.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module/Collection.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module/Collection.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][ERROR]: Caught exception: Token ; not found after index 22
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/System/Config/Shipcode.php
[2018-07-27 05:03:21][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/System/Config/Shipcode.php
[2018-07-27 05:20:58][INFO]: Starting module structure converter
[2018-07-27 05:20:58][INFO][stage: M1][codePool: local]: Processing M1 codepool
[2018-07-27 05:20:58][INFO][stage: M1][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Processing Module
[2018-07-27 05:20:58][INFO][stage: M2][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Converting 10 files found in module
[2018-07-27 05:20:58][INFO][stage: M2][codePool: local][module: Custom_Module]: Ending module structure converter
[2018-07-27 05:21:48][INFO]: Starting etc config xml converter for D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst
[2018-07-27 05:21:48][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\.\module.xml
[2018-07-27 05:21:48][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\.\config.xml
[2018-07-27 05:21:48][INFO]: Created M2 config file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/etc\adminhtml\system.xml
[2018-07-27 05:21:48][INFO]: Ending etc config xml converter
[2018-07-27 05:22:58][INFO]: Starting layout xml converter for D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst
[2018-07-27 05:22:58][WARNING]: 0 layout files were converted
[2018-07-27 05:22:58][INFO]: Ending layout xml converter
[2018-07-27 05:23:48][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Helper/Data.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Helper/Data.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mode.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mode.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module/Collection.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Could not map table name Custom_Module of type module
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][WARNING]: Can not map table : 'Custom_Module/module'
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Mysql4/Module/Collection.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/System/Config/Shipcode.php
[2018-07-27 05:23:49][INFO]: Finished processing file D:\xampp\htdocs\mi\dst/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/System/Config/Shipcode.php
```

Is the official migration tool include the feature to convert the setup script ?